# Leaving no space between subfigures using package subcaption

Tags: spacing, subfloats, subcaption

I want to draw a `figure` consisting of multiple subfigures. For this, I am using the `subcaption` package, since the LaTeX Wikibook suggests [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) that both `subfigure` and `subfig` are deprecated.

The subfigures have rectangular borders, and I want no space at all in between subfigures. This should, in theory, be possible by leaving no space in between `subfigure` environments and inserting graphics which are exactly as wide as the `subfigure` environments' width. However, there remain this little horizontal gaps in between the subfigures that make everything look awful. I could play around using negative `\vspace{}`, but I'm looking for a "clean" solution. Is there any way to arrange subfigures to be *really* beside one another, with no gap in between?

Here is an example of the kind of code I am using in my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't believe everything a Wiki says ;-) `subfig` is not deprecated (`subfigure` is indeed obsolete, though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have spurious spaces at the end of every `subfigure`. Insert a `%` and the spaces are removed. As reference, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) Here's a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}% <-------------- Added %
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}% <-------------- Added %
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}% <-------------- Added %
  \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
       \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused. I couldn't find any spaces at the end of my lines, and still adding the % helped me fix my problem; my output looks like I wanted... I don't understand which spaces I am omitting, since there were none after the curly braces.

Comment: @MHaaZ: If you leave a line-break, that is similar to a space (commonly referred to as a spurious space). Adding `%` acts to concatenate the two lines, almost like writing `\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}`. Be sure to leave *no* spaces though. For example, the following will still insert a space `\end{subfigure} %`, since it translates to `\end{subfigure} \begin{subfigure}`. Try it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. So every time I insert a linebreak into my source file, an extra space gets added into the output? That seems weird... what am I missing? (feel free to tell me to RTFM, as long as you reference said manual :))

Comment: Just realized you included a reference at the bottom of your answer. I just saw your code and didn't keep on reading... might wanna push that link before the code so other impatient people don't miss it :)

Comment: @MHaaZ: Done. And yes, but multiple spaces are gobbled into a single one. In a similar sense, you can leave 1 line or 100 between paragraphs.